# Launch trusted file on computer from cell in Excel

Tags: excel, security, autohotkey, vba

I have a cell in my spreadsheet that has a hyperlink to a script file (AutoHotKey) and I'd like to be able to launch said script by clicking on the cell in Excel. It works but I'm always presented with a warning:

> Some files can contain viruses or otherwise be harmful to your computer. Would you like to open this file?"

I've done everything I can think of in the Trust Center to get it to allow me to open this file without having to confirm it.

Is there something in the Trust Center, or a bit of VBA, that I could use to allow access to this file (and others like it) without having to confirm my selection every time?

Comment: how about write an AHK script for your own machine that handles a new hotkey and checks if it's running in Excel, copies whatever's selected (the cell), open CMD, paste, send Enter, send Alt-Tab (to go back to Excel)... or something like that

Answer (score 1):

This solution should also work for newer Excel versions (e.g. 365)

Download Procmon:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx

1. Run Procmon.exe
2. Toggle Capture Events to off (File > Capture Events)
3. Clear the current events (Edit > Clear Display)
4. Toggle Capture Events on.
5. Click the desired hyperlink in Excel.
6. Turn Capture Events off.
7. Filter by Process=EXCEL.EXE (Filter > Filter ..) and click add
8. Filter also by Operation=RegQueryValue and Result=NAME NOT FOUND
9. Find the first entry with EditFlags in the path (use the search icon to search the filtered list)
10. Right click on that entry and select > Jump to (opens registry)
    9 Add a new DWORD type named EditFlags with the hexadecimal value 10000.

In my case it was the key `htmlfile_FullWindowEmbed`

Modified from [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/45364ac3-6289-4d46-99a4-2b4486db10fd/how-do-you-disable-hyperlink-warning-message-in-excel-2010-windows-7-professional-64bit?forum=w7itprosecurity&ppud=4)

Answer (score 0):

Please follow instructions on the following page to resolve your issue:

How to enable or disable hyperlink warning messages in 2007 Office programs and in Office 2010 programs
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/925757

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

> Please try to create/add the REG_DWORD type registry value “EditFlags”
> (with the value data "EditFlags"=dword:00010000) under the registry
> key location “HKCR\htmlfile_FullWindowEmbed\” on the same problem
> client machine.  After that, please restart the client machine and
> then try to open the PDF file through the http URL link from the Excel
> file again.

Solution found [here](https://www.rahul-oncall.com/2013/08/v-behaviorurldefaultvmlo.html)